# C# Problem with number/operator input at cursor for Payroll Calculator

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am learning the C# programming language and am making a payroll application add-on for SAP business One. I have built a customized calculator that has various commands, adding, subtracting etc. I am using Visual Studio 2010.

The output "screen" is a rich textbox named 'formula_display'.

I am able to input numbers and commands and they show properly on the formula_display from left to right i.e, `2 8 9 * <=` etc

I also have input buttons for operands e.g `(), <>, [] and {}`

My problem:

If I type, `4 * ()` and then try to input some number, e.g 9 inside the brackets (by clicking inside the () in order to place the cursor there), I'm unable to do so because the the number will appear after the bracket, i.e `4 * ()9`.

How do I modify my code to be able to fix the problem:

### Code Snippet:

```
private void btn9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (inputStatus)
        {
            formula_display.Text += btn9.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            formula_display.Text = btn9.Text;
            inputStatus = true;
        }
    }
```

Any help appreciated. I am using Windows Forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this in WPF:

```
formula_display.SelectionLength = 0;
formula_display.Text.Insert(formula_display.CaretIndex, btn9.Text);
```

and something like this in WinForms:

```
formula_display.SelectionLength = 0;
formula_display.Text.Insert(formula_display.SelectionStart, btn9.Text);
```